# Proof of Fundamental Theorem of Elimination Theory, from Vakil's FOAG

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, projective-schemes

I've been working the last section of Chapter 7 of Vakil's FOAG, namely the one on the Fundamental Theorem of Elimination Theory. I'm not entirely sure if I've understood the proof correctly, especially the following paragraph:
[image]

Here's what I make of this. First of all, since $Z$ is closed, it's something of the form $V(f_1,\ldots)$. Now we want to see if a particular $p\in \text{Spec} A$ is also in $\pi(Z)$. Now $p$ is in this image iff there's some $p'$ in each affine open $U_j = \text {Spec }A[x_0/x_j,\ldots,x_n/x_j]$, which as a prime ideal contracts to $p$ under the usual map of rings produced in the opposite direction. Since we're interested in only primes that contract to $p$, we may "throw out" everything else by working only with $k(p)[x_0/x_j,\ldots,x_n/x_j]$ in each of these cases, and as a result, we may just work with $Proj_{\bullet} k(p)[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$. If there is a point $q$ at which the images of the $f_i$ vanish then there's a corresponding prime ideal which contracts to $p$ via the corresponding map of rings, and thus $p\in \pi(Z)$.

Next, there is a proof of the fact that if we have homogeneous elements $g_i$ cutting out a closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$, for some field $k$, then the coefficients of these $g_i$ satisfy a Zariski closed condition. I think I understand this bit of the proof and I don't include it here.

Finally, there is the following exercise:
[image]

To this I would say that from the work done in the first paragraph, we work with $k = k(p)$ in the last paragraph above. This would give us that the images of the coefficients of $f_i$ in $k(p)$ satisfy a Zariski closed condition (namely a number of determinants being $0$, in some $k(p)$'s). This means that we're looking for precisely those prime ideals where the determinant is $0$, which is of course closed and we are done.

Is my understanding of the situation correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are interested in showing that $\pi :\mathbb{P}^n_{A_0} \to \mathrm{Spec}\ A_0$ is a closed map.

Let $Z\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_{A_0}$ be a closed subset (in the Zariski topology). Unpacked, this means that $Z = V_+(T)$, where $T$ is a set of homogeneous elements $T= \{f_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $A_0[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$.  We WTS that $\pi(Z)$ is closed in $\mathrm{Spec}\ A$.

Hence, if we denote by
$$
\varphi: A_0[x_0,\cdots,x_n] \to \kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)[x_0,\cdots,x_n]
$$
the ring map induced by $A_0 \to \kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)$ (for each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}_0 \in \mathrm{Spec}\ A_0$), then we have

\begin{align*}
\pi(Z) &= \{\pi(\mathfrak{p})\mid \mathfrak{p} \in \bigcap_{i \in I} V_+(f_i) \text{ in }A_0[x_0,\cdots, x_n]\}\\
&=  \{ \mathfrak{p}_0 \in \mathrm{Spec}\ A_0\mid \bigcap_{i \in I}V_+(\varphi_{\mathfrak{p}_0} f_i) \neq \emptyset \text{ in } \mathbb{P}^n_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)} \} 
\end{align*}

To see why this is true, consider the tower of cartesian diagrams
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
V_+(\varphi f_i) @>\therefore \ \varphi^{-1}(-)>> V_+(f_i) \\
@V\therefore \ \text{closed embedding}VV @VV\text{closed embedding} V \\
\mathbb{P}^n_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)} @>\varphi^{-1}(-)>> \mathbb{P}^n_{A_0}\\@VVV @VV\pi V \\
\mathrm{Spec}\ \kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0) @>>> \mathrm{Spec}\ A
\end{CD}

which says that $V_+(\varphi f_i)$ is fiber of $\mathfrak{p}_0$ under the map $\pi|_{V_+(f_i)}$: i.e.
$$
V_+(\varphi f_i) = \pi|_{V_+(f_i)}^{-1}(\mathfrak{p_0}) \text{ as topological spaces}
$$

Vakil's argument supposedly demonstrates why this gives a closed set.

EDIT: (commenting on the remaining part of the argument, i.e. considerations for Exercise 8.4K in the 2023 version): some careful thought is required to make sense of what it means to replace $k$ with $A_0$. Keep in mind that point by point, we can get rather different residual fields $\kappa(\mathfrak{p_0})$, where $\mathfrak{p} \in \mathrm{Spec}\ A_0$. For example, consider $A_0 = \mathbb{Z}$. This could, a priori, affect for each $\mathfrak{p}_0$, the linear map that we test for "failure of surjectivity" on. The reason that this is not the case (i.e. that we can describe the situation with the same polynomial constraints) is because (i) determinants are polynomials given by unit coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, and (ii) the dimensions of $S_N$ and $\deg\varphi f$ do not depend on the choice of $\mathfrak{p}_0$.

Next, to say that we have proven the result since this is a 'Zariski closed condition' is rather unsatisfying to me. To complete the proof, some careful unpacking of the situation is necessary.

Firstly, we see that the linear maps involved are given by 'matrices $M_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)}$ in infinite dimensional affine space $\mathbb{A}_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)}$' (this can be made precise by thinking of ideals of polynomial rings).

Now because, $M_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)}$ corresponds to a maximal ideal (the one given by the evaluation map), our Zariski-closed condition can be interpreted properly as

$$V(M_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)})\cap V(R)_{\subseteq{\mathbb{A}_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)}}} \neq \emptyset$$

where $R$ is the collection of polynomial constraints describing the failure of surjectivity. Here, we are focusing on the situation for each degree $N$, so for ease of notation, we omit indexing everything by $N$.

Next, we unpack the fact that $M_{A_0} \mapsto M_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)}$ via 'reduction mod $\mathfrak{p_0}$ of coordinates'. This really says that $r_{\mathfrak{p}_0}^{-1}V(M_{A_0}) = V(M_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)})$, where $r_{\mathfrak{p_0}}:\mathbb{A}_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p_0})} \to \mathbb{A}_{A_0}$ is the obvious map. By an analogous argument to ours above, we deduce that the Zariski-closed condition is equivalent to

$$\pi(Z) = \chi (V(M_{A_0}) \cap V(R)_{\subseteq \mathbb{A}_{A_0}} )  \text{ in } \mathrm{Spec}\ A_0$$

where $\chi: \mathbb{A}_{A_0} \to \mathrm{Spec}\ A_0$ is the canonical map. Why should the image of a closed set be closed? This is not true in general, but we have the identification $$\mathrm{Spec}\ A_0 \cong V(M_{d,A_0})$$ induced by the evaluation-at-$M_{d,A_0}$ homomorphism. Hence, when restricted to $V(M_{d,A_0})$, we have that $\chi|_{V(M_{d,A_0})}$ is now a homeomorphism sending $V(M_{d,A_0})\cap V(R_d)_{\subseteq \mathbb{A}_{A_0}}$ to a closed set.

Comment: A friendly tip for the future: while editing to improve a post can be valuable, there is such a thing as overdoing it (this is the second-most edited post on the site today, for instance). In the future, before posting an answer, please try to get it to a point where it doesn't need 8 revisions inside the first 8 hours.

Comment: thank you very much for the tip! I'm new to submitting, and didn't know about the guidelines to adhere to ... I'll keep it in mind in the future. Perhaps, to elaborate more on how I ended up making so many edits, I have discovered in the past few hours that the remainder of Vakil's argument requires a lot more unpacking that I had expected, which left me confused about the situation, and now rather unsatisfied with my final answer ...

Comment: Improving your post is generally good, and you shouldn't feel trapped in to a final answer here if it really isn't what you want. I'd just suggest doing a bit more drafting before posting. If you're looking for a place to write and revise more, [there is a place to draft posts on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) in addition to other options like locally on your computer.